# Sqlite - How to order a list of parent posts based on children

Tags: sqlite, sorting, parent-child

I'm trying to get a list of all of the parent posts in my database sorted by the most recent activity to that thread. That means check the most recent post to that thread - if there's children posts then check their most recent date, if not then the parent's date.

I have one table called "posts" that consists of the following:

If a post is a parent (first post of thread): Topic is not null, Parent_ID is null. It would look like this:

```
ID | Name | Message | Date | File | Topic | Parent_ID
=====================================================
1  | Joe  | Wee!    | Date | File | Blah! | NULL
```

If a post is a child (a post in a thread = parent's ID): Topic is null, Parent_ID is not null. It would look like this:

```
ID | Name | Message | Date | File | Topic | Parent_ID
=====================================================
2  | Mike | Hi!     | Date | File | NULL  | 1
```

I've gotten really close. I think it has something to do with the [With Clause](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html). This is what I came up with so far:

```
WITH threads AS (
  SELECT ID,Name,Date,File,Topic,Parent_ID FROM posts WHERE Parent_ID IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Parent_ID,Name,Date,File,Topic,Parent_ID FROM posts WHERE Parent_ID NOTNULL ORDER BY Date DESC
  )
SELECT * FROM threads GROUP BY ID ORDER BY Threads.date;
```

I already know I can search for similar questions. I've already tried and still haven't come to an exact conclusion. Any help would be appreciated.

Also, should I change my table up? Maybe add a thread column or even a thread table or something to make things easier?

Comment: Are you familiar with recursive CTEs?

Comment: Not familar, but I was reading up on the With clause about it. Basically searches your search you made previously, right? So then I can do `WITH RECURSIVE threads as... etc` ?

Comment: Also, is this something easier to do in PHP? Get all results from the table and do some sorting in PHP from the results array?

Comment: good examples of CTEs with parent/child hierarchy here: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AllDates` is a standard tree walk, and collects all dates for each topic; the `TopID` is kept through all iterations so that the last date can be associated with it.
`LastDates` then throws away all rows that are not the last date.

```
WITH RECURSIVE AllDates(TopID, ID, Date) AS (
  SELECT ID, ID, Date
  FROM Threads
  WHERE Parent_ID IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT AllDates.TopID, Threads.ID, Threads.Date
  FROM AllDates
  JOIN Threads ON AllDates.ID = Threads.Parent_ID
),
LastDates(ID, LastDate) AS (
  SELECT TopID, max(Date)
  FROM AllDates
  GROUP BY TopID
)
SELECT *
FROM Threads
JOIN LastDates USING (ID)
-- WHERE Parent_ID IS NULL   (not needed because of the join)
ORDER BY LastDate DESC;
```

(This would be much easier and faster if each post had a reference to the thread.)

Comment: I'll check it out. Thanks. Also, each child post references the thread by Parent_ID, which is the ID of the post that started the thread.

Comment: So all other posts are considered direct children of that top post, and there is no tree? In that case, you do not need recursion, and `LastDate` could simply go through all rows of `Threads`.